# How to make a list and a property pointing to the same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm new to entity framework and even if i know how to do it in Merise, i can't do it using code first.

In an entity User, i should have a foreign Key 'Promotion_Id'

In an entity Promotion, i should have a foreign key 'Pilote_Id' that points out to the User entity.

Here is the thing : i also have a List in Promotion which is a list of all users in a promotion. Pilote_Id is the Id of the pilote of that formation, who's, of course, a user.

I tried the following :

```
    public class User : EntityWithId
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public virtual Promotion Promotion { get; set; }     
    }
```

```
    public class Promotion : EntityWithNameAndId
    {
        //Site is another entity, the place where the promotion is 
        public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
        public virtual User Pilote { get; set; }
    }
```

(Note : EntityWithId only contains an Id and EntityWithNameAndId inherits from EntityWithId and only contains a name)

But it only results in having 2 foreign keys in User named Promotion_Id and Promotion_Id1.

I already maked the whole thing work by changing

`public virtual User Pilote { get; set; }`

with

`public virtual Guid PiloteId { get; set; }`

But i want some consistency in my entities so.. Is there a correct way to achieve this ?

Comment: I'm unsure about what exactly you are asking. But you should check out https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Why are your members `virtual`?

Comment: @swforlife i was aware of dataannotations but it wasn't working for me.. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to use explicit mapping to achieve this:

In the OnModelCreating() for your context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
   .HasOptional(u => u.Promotion)
   .WithRequired(p => p.Pilote)
   .Map(u => u.MapKey("PiloteId"); // EF6
   // .HasForeignKey("PilotId") // EF Core
```

This assumes that a user may, or may not have a Promotion, but all promotions have a Pilot.
The Promotion.Users will probably map ok by convention using a UserId on the promotion table, but if there is any issue there:

However, there is a big caveat with this approach which relates to the schema, not EF. There is no restriction/guard that will ensure that the Pilot is one of the Users associated with the promotion. A PiloteId could point to any user, and that user's promotionId may be different.

In any case, the logic around managing who is the pilot will need to be done by code, but this means either checking IDs for valid combinations, or something like:

If a User can only be associated to 1 Promotion, and one user on that promotion can be the Pilot, then you could consider adding a flag to User called "IsPilot".

Then in Promotion:

```
public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
[NotMapped]
public User Pilote
{
   get { return Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.IsPilote); }
   set 
   {   
      var newPilote = Users.Single(u => u.UserId == value.UserId); // Ensure the user nominated for Pilote is associated with this Promotion.
      var existingPilote = Pilote;
      if (existingPilote != null)
          existingPilote.IsPilote = false;
      newPilote.IsPilote = true;
   }
}
```

If users can be assigned to multiple promotions then you will want to update the schema and mappings to support a many-to-many relationship between user and promotions, such as a UserPromotions table containing UserId and PromotionId. In this case I would consider assigning the IsPilote in this table / linking entity, but again this would need logic to ensure that rules around 1 pilot per promotion, and whether a user can be pilot for more than one promotion.

Comment: modelBuilder was the solution, it helps me binding my FKs correctly. Thank you for such a detailed answer to a so poorly explained behaviour !